# Custom Post Type rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, url-rewriting

I'm trying to link to custom post types via url. So I have CPT 'forums' (example.com/forums) and CPT 'topics' (example.com/topics)

I am trying to achieve a url of the two combined (for CPT 'topics') plus adding meta data in between (example.com/forums/forumname/topic/topicname) is this possible?

```
    //register post type
    register_post_type( 'forums', array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies' => array(  ),  
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'forums' ),
    )
);
```

which works with the correct url (example.com/forums/).

```
//register post type
register_post_type( 'topics', array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag'), 
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array( 
        'slug' => 'forums/topic',
        'with_front' => true
         ),
    )
);
```

which breaks the permalinks for CPT 'topics'. I don't understand URL rewriting very well and need someone to walk me through it a little, or at least point me in the right direction. I have been reading guides but I just get more confused.

Answer (score 2):

They key thing to understand about rewrite rules is that they only work as long as they are perfectly *unambiguous*.

You have an *idea* in your head what `example.com/forums/forumname/topic/topicname` means so it makes sense to you. When WP gets this URL it has *no remote clue* what it means, it's just a bunch of words. Then it goes to rewrite rules and seeks the rule that will "translate" it to the context it *does* understand (query variables).

So as soon as URL can be explained by *more than one rule* it all breaks down. For native post types and taxonomies it is all carefully designed so that rules don't overlap. Such as categories have to have `/category/` and so on.

With custom stuff you have more freedom to define things and so more freedom to *break* things by creating overlapping rules.

So *in general* you should just avoid any overlap in slugs and such, as much as possible.

If you *do* need overlap your life gets harder. It is still doable, but you will have to dive quite deeply to debug rules being created. Likely you will also need to construct more tight rewrite rule for your situation from scratch, since "easy" way with registration functions probably won't cut it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rarst. Can you point me to any good guides for noobies?

Comment: Not really, _expert_ people tend to run away from WP rewrite implementation screaming. :) Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer plugin is my staple to see what is going on with the rules https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/